# 301 Redirects for Changed Permalink Structure & Category Base

Tags: permalinks, redirect, htaccess

I'm redeveloping a site on a fresh WP install. The old site had the following permalink structure:

domain.com/CATEGORY/POSTNAME/

The new site has the following permalink structure:

domain.com/YEAR/MONTH/POSTNAME/

I need to set up a 301 redirect in htaccess that correctly redirects the old posts. I've found a lot of rewrite rules for the opposite way (YEAR/MONTH/POSTNAME/ to CATEGORY/POSTNAME/) but none for the way I need.

I prefer not to use a plugin. It appears that all the redirection plugins don't work. But, if Dean's Permalink Migration is recommended I'll use it.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out or are you still looking for help?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress actually 301's these out of the box! It handles a number of basic structures by default, so unless you're switching to or from a very unique configuration (e.g. `/blog/%postname%/`), it will probably work.

Comment: Let's assume for a moment that this is not a fresh WP install and that old posts need 301 redirects. WordPress doesn't handle this out of the box

Comment: @AlxVallejo, sure it does. If you're having issues, you should open a new question about why that isn't working for you (especially instead of downvoting a perfectly legitimate answer to someone else's question).

Comment: Your saying that if you change the permalink structure WordPress will automatically redirect the old permalink structure which is incorrect.

Comment: @AlxVallejo Depending on the redirect structure, yes, it is correct. For instance, take an existing WP install with a "Day and name" permalink structure, and change it to `/%category%/%postname%/` and the day and name urls still work and 301 redirect to the new permalinks.

Comment: Hmm, sorry for the downvote, that's not the case for me though - I switched exactly as you said and was not redirected.

Comment: @AlxVallejo Then you are the exception, not the rule :-). Either a plugin, your theme, or your server config is interfering for you, but this *is how WordPress works out of the box*. Here's another answer for your reference: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/88742/does-wordpress-automatically-do-301-redirect-if-i-change-permalink