# Does WordPress automatically do 301 redirect if I change permalink

Tags: permalinks

I don't know how to check this but it seems to do the redirection when I change the permalink structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes it does.** For a long time I could not find the answer too which made worry about changing. One day I just did it and checked. The *Firefox AddOn Live-Headers* shows it very clearly.

Comment: Yes, it does, USUALLY. Best to try it and see. It handles most common changes automatically, but if you have very weird Permalinks to begin with, then it might not handle your specific case. In which case, there is likely a plugin for that.

Comment: I changed domain url in wp_config. It 301 redirect on it's own. I checked the header in chrome.